# Identifying incoming calls - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, imessage

I would like to create an app that uses incoming call as a trigger. Meaning that once there's an incoming call (user has not asnwered it yet), the app will be notified.
I have found [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590).

Will it solve the issue or is there other solution?
I hope it's obvious but the the question is for NON-jailbroken phones.

Is it possible to get caller ID in such scenario?

Is there a way to identify text or iMessage once they have been received in the phone?

Answer (score 4):

`CTCall` is your only option. It will generally allow your app to receive a notification **if it's in the foreground**, but it won't give you details about the caller identity, just the call state.

It isn't possible to get information on SMS /iMessages.

Comment: How is it possible for the Truecaller ios app to detect the number?